Android Emulator is not connecting To Internet (No Internet Connection)
Android Emulator is not connecting to Internet. Wifi inside emulator says No Internet. Tried all possible solutions from all links, websites, and even from youtube. Still no solution. Please help
Tried installing new android studio, new emulator, google dns etc etc

Does this answer your question? Android emulator not able to access the internet

@Cam can u pls help me on this.. its been 3 days no answer on google solved my problem
